# How to use the word "smear" between two people?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I have two people (e.g: Sally and James). I want to damage the reputation of Sally in front of James, but I don't want to use "**in front of**" if it means that literally.

"**Smear**" is the word that I have to use in order to achieve that definition. So, I would say:

I created the stealing-money scene to smear Sally ____ James.

Comment: In a context like this, I don't think you'd really need to worry about _in front of_ being interpreted as "literally" in front of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did it **to make Sally *look bad* in front of James** or you did it **to smear Sally**.  It wouldn't be ungrammatical to include "in front of James" in the sentence with **smear**,  but it wouldn't be idiomatic.

If James is not there to behold the money-stealing scene, but is the intended audience of your smear campaign, you did it to **make Sally look bad *in the eyes of* James**.

Comment: Are you suggesting that "to make Sally look bad in the eyes of James" is better than "smear Sally in the eyes of James"? - I'm doing a revision for the story, and I came across it.

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that it is much better, because "smear {someone} in the eyes of {someone else}" is not something a native speaker would say, any more than we would say "praise {someone} in the eyes of {someone else}".  The verbs that we would use are "make someone look|appear|seem {adjective} in the eyes of {someone else}"

Answer (score 2):

You can use **in / to the eyes of**.

[Definition:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+eyes+of)

> In someone's view or opinion

Comment: It is great :) I will use "in the eyes of" since it fits the situation I intend.

Comment: @TasneemZh You can use both "in" or "to".